# NativeScript Playground App on iOS 14.0 (18A373) crash directly after start

Tags: nativescript

I have installed the NativeScript Playground App on my iPhone XR with iOS 14.0 (18A373) and the app directly crash after start. So I can not scan the QR code from play.nativescript.com

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a common problem with running Nativescript apps on iPhones with iOS 14.
My app, which has been fine for the past year, suddenly failed and I'm now trying to find a solution as rebuilding with XCode 12 also fails...

https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/8867
https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/8916

Follow up:

I got it working in Xcode 12 though not entirely clear how... basically I did this:

1. installed "tns-ios": "6.5.2"
2. tns platform remove ios, tns platform add ios
3. tns build ios --release
4. Went to XCode and selected Product > Archive (which rebuilds it)

This build succeeds and when deployed to the App Store it worked in FlightTest.

Comment: I have tried tns run ios and still facing the same crash after tns ios 6.5.2. Can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

This fix is to update tns-ios to 6.5.2 but you also have to make a change to your Podfile and build.xcconfig. I wrote a tutorial on the steps I took to fix the issue: https://timleland.com/how-to-fix-nativescript-issue-with-ios14-and-xcode-12/

Answer (score 0):

Playground and Preview Updates are now available with iOS 14 compliance:
https://twitter.com/NativeScript/status/1325994280003891200

- NativeScript Playground v1.9.0
- NativeScript Preview 1.31.0

[image]